# MQTT with HiveMQ seems to reset config limits to default if disconnecting abruptly

Tags: configuration, mqtt, hivemq

I have a hivemq broker running a cluster with 2 nodes and a console application that connects and sends and receives messages.

I've changed the configuration so that it can queue more than 1000 messages and originally when I start the service it sends 1900 messages and queues them, after the client connects all of these messages are received.

When I restart the service only 1000 messages are received. So I extended the console application to disconnect the clients cleanly and then reconnect them, send another 1900 messages and all of them were received again. But after restarting the application only 1000 were received.

Does anybody know why this might be happening?

Node 1 config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hivemq>
<listeners>
    <tcp-listener>
        <port>1884</port>
        <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address>
    </tcp-listener>
</listeners>

<mqtt>
    <max-client-id-length>65535</max-client-id-length>
    <max-topic-length>65535</max-topic-length>
    <incoming-bandwidth-throttling>0</incoming-bandwidth-throttling>
    <no-connect-idle-timeout>30000</no-connect-idle-timeout>
    <max-queue-size>100000</max-queue-size>
    <max-queued-messages>100000</max-queued-messages>
    <server-receive-maximum>10000</server-receive-maximum>
</mqtt>

<throttling>
    <max-connections>-1</max-connections>
    <max-message-size>268435456</max-message-size>
    <outgoing-limit>0</outgoing-limit>
    <incoming-limit>0</incoming-limit>
</throttling>

<cluster>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</cluster>

<anonymous-usage-statistics>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</anonymous-usage-statistics>

</hivemq>
```

Node 2 config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hivemq>
<listeners>
    <tcp-listener>
        <port>1885</port>
        <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address>
    </tcp-listener>
</listeners>

<mqtt>
    <max-client-id-length>65535</max-client-id-length>
    <max-topic-length>65535</max-topic-length>
    <incoming-bandwidth-throttling>0</incoming-bandwidth-throttling>
    <no-connect-idle-timeout>30000</no-connect-idle-timeout>
    <max-queue-size>100000</max-queue-size>
    <max-queued-messages>100000</max-queued-messages>
    <server-receive-maximum>10000</server-receive-maximum>
</mqtt>

<throttling>
    <max-connections>-1</max-connections>
    <max-message-size>268435456</max-message-size>
    <outgoing-limit>0</outgoing-limit>
    <incoming-limit>0</incoming-limit>
</throttling>

<cluster>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</cluster>

<control-center>
    <listeners>
        <http>
            <port>8081</port>
            <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address>
        </http>
    </listeners>
</control-center>   

<anonymous-usage-statistics>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</anonymous-usage-statistics>

</hivemq>
```

Comment: From a quick look at the [docs](https://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/4.7/user-guide/configuration.html#msg-queue-size) (or [this](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-community-edition/wiki/MQTT-Specific-Configuration#queued-messages)) it looks like `max-queue-size` should be within a `<queued-messages>` node? It would help to know what version of HiveMQ you are running along with more detail on the meaning on "sends 1900 messages and queues them" (sending QOS1+ messages to previously subscribed topic?).

Comment: thank you, adding the `<queued-messages>` node has worked. I'm using version `4.7.1`. I don't understand why it would work the first time round though